# How do I set a Python builtin Exception's message attribute when I raise it

Tags: python, exception

I know I can specify an arbitrary number of arguments to an Exception (or any subclass thereof) when I raise it, but I see that Exceptions have a message attribute which isn't populated.

```
def throw():
    raise Exception("This is my message", 10)

try:
    throw()
except Exception as E:
    print "message = ", E.message
    print E.args
```

produces

```
message = 
("This is my message", 10)
```

What I would like to do is raise a variety ValueErrors depending on how or why a value in my function isn't valid. I would also like to attach a code, so something like

```
raise ValueError(1, "You need to supply a string value")
# or
raise ValueError(2, "Not a valid place name") #but it is a valid string
```

I'm writing a code that runs callbacks supplied by the user, and I expect the user's functions to raise ValueErrors in certain situations, but their callback can also call into some library functions I provide, and I want to be able distinguish between the user's ValueErrors and Mine.

I know I can subclass the ValueError and check for that exception type explicitly, but that seems like overkill. These are all errors with user supplied values after all, so I would like to use the first argument to the exception as a code, and then somehow set the message attribute explicitly

```
raise ValueError(10, message = "Error 10 is something quite specific")
```

The above doesn't work, because exceptions don't accept keyword arguments on **init**.

Comment: Why not create your own Error class ?

Comment: Like I said, I know I can do that, I'm wondering if that is not the wrong way to go about things like this, since there a message attribute that is going unused. I assume I should be able to set that and use the args for something else

Comment: What is the int argument for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message attribute is set when the `Exception` instance is created with a single argument. Otherwise it is empty:

```
In [1]: Exception(42).message
Out[1]: 42

In [2]: Exception('foo').message
Out[2]: 'foo'

In [3]: Exception('foo', 42).message
Out[3]: ''
```

Of course you can create an instance of `Exception` and manually set its `.message` attribute before raising:

```
e = Exception()
e.message = 'test'
raise e
```

But it would probably make a lot of sense to use a custom exception class instead.

Also note that `Exception` does not have a `message` attribute in Python 3, only `args`.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I appreciate that the sub-classed exceptions are a better way to do it, but at least I now know why the message attribute isn't being set for my exceptions (because they multiple args)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* pass multiple argument when you raise an exception:

```
try:
    raise ValueError("message", 1, 2, 3)
except ValueError as e:
    print e
    print e[1]
```

The exception object is simply a tuple, and you can access any item in te tuple in array[index] manner.

**OUTPUT:**

```
('message', 1, 2, 3)
1
```